# Real-time chats using Redis - how not to lose messages?

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, chat, real-time

I want to implement a real-time chat. My main db is PostgreSQL, with the backend written in NodeJS. Clients will be mobile devices.

As far as I understand, to achieve real-time performance for messaging, I need to use Redis. 
Therefore, my plan was to use Redis for the X most recent messages between 2 or more people(group chat) , for example 1000, and everything is synced and backed in my main Db which is PostgreSQL.
However, since Redis is essentially just RAM, the chat history can be too "vulnerable", owing to the volatile nature of storing data in RAM. 
So if my redis server has some unexpected and temporary failure, the recent messages in conversations would be lost.

What are the best practices nowaydays to implement something like this?
Do I simply need to persist Redis data to disk? but in that case, wouldn't that hurt performance, since it will increase the write time for each message sent ?

Or perhaps I should just prepare a recovery method, that fetches the recent history from PostgreSQL in case my redis chat history list is empty?

P.S - while we're at it, could you please suggest a good approach for maintaining the status of users (online/offline) ? Is it done with Redis as well?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best practices nowaydays to implement something like
>   this? Do I simply need to persist Redis data to disk? but in that
>   case, wouldn't that hurt performance, since it will increase the write
>   time for each message sent?

- Yes, enabling persistence will impact performance of redis.
- The best bet will be run a quick [benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) with the expected IOPS and type of operations from your application to identify impacts on IOPS with persistence enabled.
- RBD vs AOF:

  - With RDB persistence enabled, the parent process does not perform disk I/O to store changes to data to RDB. Based on the values of `save points`, redis forks a child process to perform RDB.
  - However, based on the configuration of `save points`, you may loose  data written after last save point - in case of the event of server restart or crash if data was not saved from last save point
  - If your use case can not tolerate to the data loss for this period, you need to look at the AOF persistence method. AOF will keep track of all write operations, that can be used to construct data upon server restart event.
  - AOF with fsync policy set to every second can be slower, however, it can be as good as RDB if fsync is disabled.
  - Read the trade-offs of using RDB or AOF: https://redis.io/topics/persistence#redis-persistence

> P.S - while we're at it, could you please suggest a good approach for
>   maintaining the status of users (online/offline) ? Is it done with
>   Redis as well?

- Yes

Comment: thank you for the help. I'm not familiar with Redis, do server shutdowns happen often? and for how much time, until it's able to recover?
my scale isn't huge, but I wouldn't want my users to lose messages here and there, do the popular chat apps use Redis with AOF ? or other DBs altogether (Cassandra, etc.) ?

Also, is it better to fetch history from Postgres and only then subscribe to Redis? will not somehow end up in a case where users wouldn't know if they missed some messages?
thanks again!

Comment: frequency of going servers down depends on your environment. However, you can configure redis-sentinel to maintain HA. This will definitely increase availability of your system. If you plan to use redis-cluster, a slave will be promoted to master.  Fetching online/offline status of the user from redis is going to be better than Cassandra in terms of performance.